# How to make to ListView scroll down together

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a project and I have to make two synchronize to ListView. I search during all day long and I was not able to find a answer to my problem...
I would like to have something looking like this : [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vzZa.jpg)

As you can see, Items can have different size and so they may not be right aligned (that's why I can't use a grid layout), and I may have to handle a big amount of items so I cannot just put everything in a scrollview (I tried at the beginning, believe me it's not possible), 
So now I have 2 ListView but they are totally independent one from the other...
Do someone have a solution ? I am ready to change the type of view if something looks better, or two use different librairies.
I hope I was clear, once again I just want that make scroll a listview make the other one scroll the same number of pixel (not number of element). I want that this two ListView look like one...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a StaggeredGridLayout (Here's a tutorial http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

I wouldn't recommend synchronising listviews as finding and setting the scrolled pixel values is quite hacky.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help, I followed the tutorial and things goes well :D I would never find it by myself...